# Microsoft Excel 2010 Workbook Comparison Code

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2007

So I have these two workbooks, the data will not be in the same format, but will have a unique identifying number (like a ID Key in Access).

The goal of my code would be to identify rows with the same UIN then compare across the row to make sure the numbers match.

Normally I'd do this in Access, but job limits exist and until I can get them on-board excel it is.

Any tips would be welcome

Answer (score 0):

You can create a copy for the first sheet and copy the second one at the end of the first the columns should be the same, you can sort by UIN you will have each same code one down the other you can use conditional formatting to format duplicates for the same UIN or Subtotal sum, if all columns are numbers, at each change in UIN to compare each 2 rows (multiplying one row with -1 and sum will give 0 means match)